# Why deleting an element in a linkedlist costs O(1)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

As the textbook shown, a linkedlist is good for those situations where it frequently inserts or deletes since it costs O(1) for these operations. However, a node of linkedlist doesnot contains any pointer that points to the previous node. So if I need to delete a specific node, I may have to find the previous node and change the information of its `next` pointer, which costs O(n). Or, if not, the reference for the next node will be affected. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
// These operations have to find the previous node of the position, so it costs O(n).
node* erase(node* head, int pos);
node* erase(node* node_to_delete);

// This operation costs O(1), but it affect the validation of the reference of the next node.
node* erase(node* position) {
    if (position == _last)
        return _last;
    auto tmp = position -> next;
    position -> val = position -> next -> val;
    position -> next = position -> next -> next;
    delete tmp;
    if (tmp == _last) 
        _last = position;
    _size--;
    return position;
}
```

I expect insert or delete the node in O(1).

Comment: There are really two types of lists: Single-linked lists, which seems to be what you have; And double-linked lists, which also have a "previous" pointer. Whatever book you're reading must be using a double-linked lists.

Comment: With that said, removing a node from a double-linked list is only O(1) **iff** you already have the node. Something users of your list shouldn't really have. That means the users of the list will first have to find the position of the node they want to remove, which then makes it all O(n) anyway (unless it's the very common special cases of removing the first node of the list, or (if you have a pointer to the tail node) the last node of the list).

Comment: Perhaps shedding some light on the extensive use of `std::vector` and the comparatively sparse use of `std::list`.

Comment: The other caveat for singly-linked lists is removal of the first node will be O(1).  Where a `head` and `tail` pointer are used, insert at `head` or `tail` are also O(1).

Comment: It is the "looking" for an element that is O(n) in a list. Once you found it you only have to manage some pointers and delete a node (and that takes constant time)

Comment: By the way if your textbook is showing code like that... it is a datastructures book not a C++ tutorial. Note that in C++ we just use std::list.

Comment: Also note that O(1) doesn't mean "fast", but "always takes abiut the same time". If you have 1 hour against n seconds, O(n) could be much faster if n is small.

Comment: *As the textbook shown...*  Which textbook?  What ISBN?  Who is the author?  What chapter and page?

Comment: There's a bit of sloppiness in the discussion here. Removing a node from a linked list is O(1). **Finding** the element to remove, given only the head node, is O(N). So **finding and removing** an element given only the head node is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

The code does not delete the current node at `position`, instead the code emulates deletion of the current node by copying the next node's data and next pointer into the current node, then it deletes the next node. This is why the code is O(1). If there are any existing pointers to the next node, then those pointers become invalid since it it the next node that is being deleted. The code fails to delete anything if `position` is `_last`, since there is no next node, instead this is the one case where it should require O(n) time to scan the list in order to delete the actual last node and update `_last` to point to the prior node.

Comment: It's O(1) under the assumption that copying the data is O(1). This is of course toy code. Better code would use std::move, because that's often O(1) even when copying is O(N). (e.g. `std::string`)

Comment: @MSalters -- removing an element from a linked list is O(1) because it isn't affected by the number of elements in the list. Full stop.

Comment: @MSalters - std::move() "may" just move a pointer but not always. Visual Studio 2015 std::move(std::string) just copies the string, and changes the source string to an empty string.  I don't think the OP was concerned about the time it takes to copy data from one node to another when asking about O(1) time complexity for a delete.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's not O(list size), no, but it can be O(element size).

Comment: @MSalters -- yes, exactly: if you double the number of elements in the list, the time needed to remove an element doesn't change. That doesn't depend on any assumptions; it's simply how the performance scales with the size of the list. The time needed to copy an element doesn't affect that in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you have to start with a pointer to the node itself. You can work with pointers to *preceding* nodes.

Comment: Correct. The O(1) case is the _best_ case. If you have only the head node, deletion of the N'th node takes an O(N) list walk. With a double-linked list, finding the adjacent nodes to re-link is O(1). But with a single-linked list, you need the preceding node as you cannot get that in O(1) from the node to delete.

Comment: @MSalters - or an XOR list, where a single link is replaced by an XOR of pointers to previous and next nodes, but this requires "iterators" to have two pointers, previous and current node:  [xor list](https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/xorlist.cpp) .